# How to send a notification daily at a particular time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I know this question has been asked many times and I have implemented the solutions provided. However, I'm getting notifications many time when I launch the app and repeatedly over and over again. It is set to receive notification after 24 hours. Please help.

in onCreate I'm calling the function below:

```
private void setDailyCoins() {  
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);   
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HomeActivity.this, 0, intent1, 0);
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,02);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 02);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

and While receiving the notification :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
int MID;
private ParseQuery<ParseObject> query;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("noti " + when);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            com.socialcurrency.teenpatti.LoginActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.teen_patti_icon)
            .setContentTitle("ppp")
            .setContentText(
                    "Please Collect 10,000 coins daily reward. Enjoy!!!")
            .setSound(alarmSound).setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
    notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    MID++;
    calltoAddCoins(context);
}
```

added the receiver in Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

Comment: However, I'm getting notifications many time when I launch the app and repeatedly over and over again. Is this happening only when you launch the app?

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, and it doesnt matter if it has been open after 24 hrs or 5 minutes.. It keeps sending me notification again at random time.

Comment: comment the notification part. see if the broadcast is triggered again and again. The alarm code looks ok

Comment: What so you see in the log? with  `System.out.println("noti " + when);`. Do you see it repeatedly??

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, I getting it repeatedly !! Just Checked it now

Comment: check where and when this `setDailyCoins()` is called. As far as i can see i don't see anything wrong with the alarm code.

Comment: @Raghunandan It is called everytime when the app launches and oncreate of HomeScreen !!!

Comment: Since you are calling the function n onCreate() when ever you launch the app you are getting notification i feel is this your main Activity?

Comment: @addy123 in onRecieve you are passing System.CurrentTimeMillis for when variable, I think this will take the current time, can you pass the time which you are setting in onCreate to the receiver and then set that passed time to when and check once?

Comment: @addy123 use shared preferences. Make sure you call the method only once. I reproduced the same effect with a sample.